# .NET 5.0 - EF - DbSet is empty after upgrade from 3.1

Tags: entity-framework, asp.net-core, dbset

One of my DbSet returns an empty list, **while data is there in db, and it used to work before upgrading to .NET 5.0**

```
var list = await context.TeamMembers.ToListAsync(); >> returns empty list
var list = await context.TeamMembers.Include(t=>t.User).ToListAsync(); >> returns empty list
```

while others are working correctly returning a populated list

```
var list2 = await context.Users.ToListAsync(); >> works fine
```

my dbsets are define like this

```
public DbSet<User> Users { get; set; }
public DbSet<TeamMember> TeamMembers { get; set; }
```

here is my table structure

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[teamMembers] ( 
    [Id] INT IDENTITY (1, 1)  NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY, 
    [UserId] INT NOT NULL,
    [PartnerId] INT NOT NULL,
    [Type] INT NOT NULL,
    [CreationDate]       DATETIME    DEFAULT (getdate()) NOT NULL,
    [ModificationUserId] INT         NOT NULL,
    [ModificationDate]   DATETIME    DEFAULT (getdate()) NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT [FK_teamMembers_Members] FOREIGN KEY ([UserId]) REFERENCES [users]([Id]), 
    CONSTRAINT [FK_teamMembers_Partners] FOREIGN KEY ([PartnerId]) REFERENCES [partners]([Id]), 
    CONSTRAINT [FK_teamMembers_ModificationUser] FOREIGN KEY ([ModificationUserId]) REFERENCES [users]([Id]),
);
```

and here is my object

```
[Table("teamMembers")]
public class TeamMember
{
    [Required]
    public int? Id { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public User User { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public int? PartnerId { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public int Type { get; set; } // 0 agency 1 Salesman

    [Required]
    public DateTime CreationDate { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public DateTime ModificationDate { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public int ModificationUserId { get; set; }
}
```

[edit]
here is the query generated by EF, if I run it manualy it returns data
(there is a joint in this one as I used .Include(...) )

```
SELECT [t].[Id], [t].[CreationDate], [t].[ModificationDate], [t].[ModificationUserId], [t].[PartnerId], [t].[Type], [t].[UserId], [u].[Id], [u].[Civility], [u].[CreationDate], [u].[CreationUserId], [u].[Email], [u].[FirstName], [u].[Identifier], [u].[Language], [u].[LastName], [u].[Login], [u].[LoginEnabled], [u].[Mobile], [u].[ModificationDate], [u].[ModificationUserId], [u].[MustResetPassword], [u].[Password], [u].[Phone], [u].[Position], [u].[ResetPasswordDate], [u].[ResetPasswordToken], [u].[RoleId], [u].[Type]
FROM [teamMembers] AS [t]
LEFT JOIN [users] AS [u] ON [t].[UserId] = [u].[Id]
```

here is the User class

```
public class User
{
    [Required]
    public int? Id { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public string FirstName { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public string LastName { get; set; }

    public string Email { get; set; }

    public string Login { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public DateTime CreationDate { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public DateTime ModificationDate { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public int CreationUserId { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public int ModificationUserId { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public short RoleId { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public short Civility { get; set; }

    public string Phone { get; set; }

    public string Mobile { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public string Position { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public short Language { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public bool MustResetPassword { get; set; }
        
    [Required]
    public short Type { get; set; } // professional/private
        
    public string Identifier { get; set; }

    [JsonIgnore]
    public string Password { get; set; }
    [Column(TypeName = "BIT")]
    public bool LoginEnabled { get; set; }
    public string ResetPasswordToken { get; set; }
    public DateTime? ResetPasswordDate { get; set; }
}
```

here is the partner class

```
public class Partner
{
    [Required]
    public int? Id { get; set; }

    public Company Company { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public User Manager { get; set; }

    public List<Invoice> Invoices { get; set; }

    [NotMapped]
    public double InvoicesAmount { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public List<ProductRetribution> ProductsRetributions { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public double Won { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public double Pending { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public double Offset { get; set; }

    // following fields are created by the system, inputs from client are discarded, no validation , but needed for mvc
    [Required] 
    public DateTime CreationDate { get; set; }
    [Required] 
    public DateTime ModificationDate { get; set; }
    [Required] 
    public int ModificationUserId { get; set; }
}
```

is there anything I am missing ?

thanks for your help

Comment: Does `SELECT * FROM [dbo].[teamMembers]` give you results? Can you check the raw SQL that EF is running against your database? Do you have any other entity configuration you're not showing here?

Comment: I have data in db, the query works, and other entities are fetched...this used to work fine...the only difference I think of is that I have foreign keys in TeamMember entity

Comment: OK, that's the first question I asked, but there are two more...

Comment: with the sql profiler I could see and replay the query created by EF, it returns data

Comment: and I dont have other config...I dont really understand what you mean by that

Comment: Not sure why you would be missing data, but I do notice that you have 3 nullable int properties in your C# model that shouldn't be nullable, especially the `Id` since that is the primary key.

Comment: I'll roll back to 3.1...This s...

Comment: Even in 3.1 you shouldn't have those properties as nullable.

Comment: they are nullable becos when I create a record, the id should be null when saving

Comment: That's not how it works. The primary key absolutely cannot be nullable. Leave it 0 when creating a new record and it will be populated with the real value by EF. Same for the others.

Comment: it did not work for me, I had to set it null otherwise it was complaining the key already existed in db, only when I set it to null it started working

Comment: Then you are doing something very wrong. It's possible that EF Core 5 has become more strict which is why this isn't working for you. I would strongly recommend you fix that issue or it will give you far more trouble in the future.

Comment: You may want to tell EF that ist is a property that is generated by the database. Add `[DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]` and probably `[Key]` for good measure

Comment: See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/generated-properties?tabs=data-annotations

Comment: just tried by removing the nullables, and it's still not working

Comment: also added [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)] & [Key] to the PK

Comment: Pls add User and Partner classes too

Comment: I noticed I had a NullReferenceException trying to use context.TeamMembers.FromSqlRaw("SELECT * FROM teamMembers") while it works fine with the User entity...I checked my data, no fields contain any null value, and I removed all nullables...wtf??

Comment: I added both classes in the question

Comment: You can verify that the connection string at runtim matches where you expect the data to be coming from by adding the following line and debugging:
`var connectionString = context.Database.GetDbConnection().ConnectionString;`
Often, depending on how you are managing your connectivity (designers, code first, etc.) the runtime connection string can end up being left pointed at an older database instance which trips people up not seeing data they are expecting. Also, a null-able PK is weird, as is putting `[Required]` on it. EF Core 5 might have stricter attribute/property expectations.

Comment: as mentioned, other entities are working fine, this app has been running and connecting to the db for one year now...I'll remove the nullables

Comment: ...And it does not work

Answer (score 0):

as it turns out, I was checking the wrong db

**the actual db has it's table completely empty**

moral of the story : don't mix 3 versions of your database on the dev server

thanks for everyone helping me out, I'll surely fix all my nullables in my tables